# Coordinates in Elliptic Curves used in cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have noticed that points on a NIST curve (secp256, secp384, etc.) or some other elliptic curves used in cryptography, when represented as `04 | x coordinate | y coordinate` in hexadecimal, the coordinates appear to have a fixed length. Is this something that is proved somewhere ? As far as the math goes, I do not see any obvious reason why would this be true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The coordinates of points on Elliptic Curves used in cryptography are in a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), thus can be expressed in bounded length, thus in fixed length. That ends the "proof". The field is $\mathbb F_p$ with some prime $p$ for all the `secp` curves.

The convention used in the question's notation is described in [sec1v2 §2.3.3](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.3), case 3 (*point compression is not being used*), with each coordinate converted per [§2.3.5](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.5), case 1 for `secp` curves, thus with conversion per [§2.3.7](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.7), that is using big-endian convention over fixed number of bytes $\lceil(\log_2 p)/8\rceil$.

Comment: This was helpful. I looked at the bit-coin elliptic curve and didn't realize that they were big-endian.

Answer (score 2):

The X9/SECG formats (uncompressed, compressed, and now-dropped hybrid) for public-key (and sometimes other) points are widely used but are not the only ones.

- [JWA/JOSE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-6.2.1) represents each coordinate as fixed-length big-endian unsigned (same as X9/SECG for GF(p) fields which are the only ones JWA uses) then converts each coordinate separately to base64url and uses it as a field in the JSON object for the key
- [COSE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9053#name-elliptic-curve-keys) also uses only GF(p) fields and starts with the SECG(/X9) coordinates, then puts in a CBOR map, in addition to generic members and the curve identifier, label -2 for the x coordinate and label -3 for either the y coordinate or a boolean value equivalent to the X9/SECG compressed parity but represented differently
- [the first version of ECDSA for XMLDSIG](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4050.html#section-3.4.3) has separate XML elements (X and Y) each containing an integer for GF(p) fields or an octetstring for GF(2^m) fields; [XMLDSIG2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-xmldsig-core2-20150723/#sec-ECKeyValue) supersedes this with the X9/SECG uncompressed format encoded in base64